# sql request repeated field

Tags: sql, teradata

I wrote this SQL query, and as you see the field ART_ID will repeat in the display, I'm looking for another way to write it without the field being repeated

```
 SSELECT   *

                FROM 
    ( SELECT  R.rng_id AS rang_id,
                R.RNG_WHS AS RNG_WHS,
                R.rng_sortie AS rng_sortie,
                R.rng_start AS rng_start,
                R.rng_end AS rng_end,
                R.RNG_ACTIF_DATE AS RNG_ACTIF_DATE,
                D.dest_type,
                D.dest_region,
                R.ART_ID

    FROM  P_STG_POSA.gss_range R
    INNER JOIN P_STG_POSA.GSS_DESTINATAIRE D ON R.rng_sortie_whs = D.dest_id 
    WHERE  rng_inactif='A' ) R

    INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT ART_ART_LIBELLE, ART_ID 
    FROM P_STG_POSA.GSS_ARTICLE 
    WHERE art_type_id= 'S4' ) A
    ON  R.art_id=A.art_id
```

Comment: Where does this `ART_ID` repeat? I can spot it only once. If you don't want it in your result simply don't select it.

Comment: i edit code, sorry

Comment: Teradata doesnt supprt Standard SQL's `JOIN USING` which would return the join column only once. Thus you need to list the columns you want instead of `*`. Or you don't use Derived Tables and write it in a single Select.

Answer (score 0):

`Select *` returns all columns, and as art_id exists twice, it will be returned twice.  Instead of `*` list the columns you want to return.

Using `Select *` is generally a bad idea anyway; it can have performance implications and makes your data harder to use for other applications.

Using select * also means that the columns a specific query returns will change if the underlying tables change, this can have serious negative effects.